# Im scared at night!

Tags: infant, night-time, anxiety, sharing, nightwaking

I'm an intermediate kid and being scared of every little sound I hear in the house is getting old and wasting precious sleeping time. Every time I'm in the sleep zone, I hear a sound like footsteps and doors close and people talking (not outside, it sounds like my brother or sister) and clicks and beeps and stuff. I know for sure everyone is asleep, but still.. and sometimes I see shadows and stuff. I know it's not real but no get scared for  second then I can't help but think about it the whole night, then I can't sleep. I need help, but I can't see a doc or therapist. What else should I do besides that and telling myself it's my imagination?

Comment: Hi, I.J. I'm very sorry to hear about your problems with fear at night (I sympathize, and am glad someone answered with good suggestions.) However, this is a parenting site, and your question has nothing to do with parenting. If you could modify it to make it [on topic for this site](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), please edit. It might be better asked on Health.SE or Cognitive Sciences.SE. (Just to clarify, do you think you're hearing voices when you know that isn't likely true? And you might add your age; it matters from a medical viewpoint.) Thanks. And welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about parenting (or being parented.)

Comment: Ear plugs and night mask? Cheap and effective.

Answer (score 2):

I am in my 50s, and sometimes I struggle with the same thing! Some things I find helpful:

- Leaving a light on in the next room
- Running a fan
- Sitting up and reading until I am really sleepy
- Music or television on with really low volume

A lot of people find sleeping with a pet helpful. Maybe that is an option for you? Good luck.